# Batch file curl POST error: 'This App Can't run on your PC'

Tags: windows, batch-file, curl

I am seeking help because of a little problem with curl whenever I use this code to send a POST using curl it gives me the error "This App Can't run on your PC" I already looked if it was a problem of my pc but it didn't work, I am not familiar with curl so I don't know how the error keeps appearing anyone can help me?

OBS: This code was working for a long time before I never changed anything I don't know if windows changed something about it but I didn't seem to get it working.

the following code is the problem:

````
:: A discord webhook link
set webhook=

:: What you want to send
set auth= 123

:: The sending
%temp%\curl.exe --silent -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" --insecure --data "{\"content\":  \"AUTH ID FOR %USERNAME%\n```asciidoc\nAUTH ID: %auth%\n\n```\n\"}" %webhook% 2 >nul
````

Comment: What is the OS upon which this is being executed? and which flavour/version of `cURL` are you using. I ask because the built-in `curl.exe` in Windows 10+ is located in `%SystemRoot%\System32` not in `%temp%`, so it appears you are either using an outdated OS or a third party alternative to the built-in utility.

Comment: Yeah, I understand my error the curl I was using it was outdated but from the real curl website. Thank you it helped me the understand where I was going wrong.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need that specific binary of curl.exe, might be better to get a new one from https://curl.se/windows/

Note that recent versions of Windows come with curl already, so you might be able to alternatively use that if available (removing `%temp%` might be all that is needed)